# Get a special folder path by passing an integer instead of the ShellSpecialFolderConstants

Tags: c#

While I know that special folders paths can be retrieved by using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`
for an example, to retrieve the path of the desktop, I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the path without passing the constant ("Desktop" in this case) but the integer refering to it instead.

To make it a bit more clear; what I want to do is the following for an example:
`Environment.GetFolderPath(0x00)` or `Environment.GetFolderPath(0)`

The final goal I want to achieve being to browse through an array with only the integers refering to said special folders so I can get the paths for various special folders in a single loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to make your code less readable? of course you can use numbers, its an enum - but it just means your code is way less readable and people need to remember what the numbers are which is unnecessary

```
       Desktop = 0,
       Programs = 2,
       Personal = 5,
       MyDocuments = 5,
       Favorites = 6,
       Startup = 7,
       Recent = 8,
       SendTo = 9,
       StartMenu = 11,
       MyMusic = 13,
       MyVideos = 14,
       DesktopDirectory = 16,
       MyComputer = 17,
       NetworkShortcuts = 19,
       Fonts = 20,
       Templates = 21,
       CommonStartMenu = 22,
       CommonPrograms = 23,
       CommonStartup = 24,
       CommonDesktopDirectory = 25,
       ApplicationData = 26,
       PrinterShortcuts = 27,
       LocalApplicationData = 28,
       InternetCache = 32,
       Cookies = 33,
       History = 34,
       CommonApplicationData = 35,
       Windows = 36,
       System = 37,
       ProgramFiles = 38,
       MyPictures = 39,
       UserProfile = 40,
       SystemX86 = 41,
       ProgramFilesX86 = 42,
       CommonProgramFiles = 43,
       CommonProgramFilesX86 = 44,
       CommonTemplates = 45,
       CommonDocuments = 46,
       CommonAdminTools = 47,
       AdminTools = 48,
       CommonMusic = 53,
       CommonPictures = 54,
       CommonVideos = 55,
       Resources = 56,
       LocalizedResources = 57,
       CommonOemLinks = 58,
       CDBurning = 59
```

Apparently Merion Huhges feels you are too stupid to be able to apply `Environment.GetFolderPath((Environment.SpecialFolder)20);` to your code yourself.

Comment: Doesnt answer the question

Comment: Thanks for the addition of the code, this actually worked and indeed, I was "too stupid" in that sense not knowing that I can apply the integer that way.

Comment: I thought given Merion had put it in comments, that adding it was unnecessary.. but there you go. Glad you like - given you also know a list of numbers now, you can just put those into an array picking out those you might want.. and use it in a for loop

Comment: He explicitly asked to loop through with an int. So there you go.